# How to add new address type (customer address) in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

how can I add three new address types same as billing and shipping in magento2?

Comment: why you need to  different type of address

Comment: @AmitBera as per our requirement, we need total 5 type of different address for marketplace.